# BTC sent from Bitcoin Core on 3rd still unconfirmed (7days)

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I sent some BTC from Bitcoin Core on 3rd Mar 2017 but it still shows as unconfirmed. This was my first sent transaction so I did not know much about fee which I learnt about in these past 7 days. However, th fee I sent still came out to be around 25satoshi/byte.

This is the transaction.
https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/c5e40d06de10aca9f5a8f594abbf9e198c72423177a6221ae52d514cdc2a317b

Could someone please suggest how can I get this back or through? If I get it back I will send it again with higher fee.

I researched a lot and read about double spent, zapwallettx etc. but dont understand at a level I can take risk to do it.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: accelerated. should be confirmed in few hours

Comment: Its confirmed now. Thanks for replyin and helpin me gettin it confirmed. I appreciate th help.